# Clone one node and its children by selecting/clicking in treeview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, treenode

How one can clone an entire node with its children by clicking or selecting node? Suppose by clicking a node its children is also selected. and then then there is no need to check if they are already selected or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//this example copies the selectednode from TreeViewTemplates to TreeForCopiedItem after you click a node.
//set the .afterselect-event of the treeview with the code below
//shouldn't be to hard to convert to C#
// Update : .clone returns an object, so use Ctype for explicit conversion

Private Sub TreeViewTemplates_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeViewTemplates.AfterSelect
    TreeForCopiedItem.Nodes.Clear()
    Dim copiedNode As TreeNode = CType(TreeViewTemplates.SelectedNode.Clone, TreeNode)
    TreeForCopiedItem.Nodes.Add(copiedNode)
End Sub
```

Comment: I wrote the commands as: `TreeNode select_node1 = new TreeNode();
            select_node1 = treeView1.SelectedNode.Clone();
            TreeNode copied_node1 = new TreeNode();
            copied_node1.Nodes.Add(select_node1);`
bt there is an error. `Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode'`.

Comment: What do you want to do with the selected/copied TreeNode?
do you want to add it to a TreeView? Or do you want it added to another TreeNode?

Comment: I want to add to another TreeNode.

Comment: Code update : .clone returns an object, so use Ctype for explicit conversion